# How to do retry on status 200 using axios-retry

Tags: javascript, axios, axios-retry

I am using [axios-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry)
I am trying that it will do retry on response condition and not on response status.
My status is 200 I think because of that it not going to retry,
My code is

```
        raxConfig: {
                retry: retry,
                retryDelay: retryDelay,
                httpMethodsToRetry: ["GET"],
                 statusCodesToRetry: [
                     [200, 300]

                 ],
                shouldRetry: (err) => {
                    const cfg = rax.getConfig(err);
                    if (cfg.data.isFinal == true) {
                        return false
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You can add response interceptor and throw error if response did not satisfy some conditions. https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: where I can put this function with https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry-axios

Comment: `retry-axios` is a wrapper under `axios`. `interceptors` - is a part of `axios`. Add response interceptor to your `axios` instance, that you use in your code, then throw an error in the interceptor, if response is look like invalid, and `retry-axios` automatically catch errors and try to resend request

Comment: I add this but the issue is then I do  return Promise.reject(error); but then its not doing retry its going to catch

Comment: `retry-axios` has option `retryCondition` (A callback to further control if a request should be retried. By default, it retries if it is a network error or a 5xx error on an idempotent request (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT or DELETE).), maybe that get you point :)

Comment: I didn't find a way of a throw network error, maybe you can give code example

Comment: Hi @VitalyMenchikovsky, any updates on this?  I found a npm lib that helps you retry on any condition instead of just status codes : https://github.com/DoSomething/node-request-retry#node-request-retry         
But it is based on another http client - request and not axios

Comment: yes issue resolved

Comment: @VitalyMenchikovsky how did you solve this?

Comment: please can you provide your full code as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to throw a 500 with an axios interceptor and then I configured an axios-retry... but that turned ugly real quick...

I ended up doing this

```
if (retry) {
    const MAX = 5;
    let tried = 0;
    do {
        response = await axios.get(url, { ...options });
        console.warn('try# ', tried++, response.data);
        await delay(1000);
    } while (response.data.ok !== 1 && tried < MAX);
} else {
    response = await axios.get(url, { ...options });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static async event( retry = 5, retryDelay = 10000) {
    //default retryDelay 10 sec
    const restURL ='www.sdfdsfds.sdfds'
    for (let i = 0; i < retry; i++) {
      const response = await this.rest(restURL);
      if (
        response.status == 200 

      ) {
        return response.data;
      }
      await this.delay(retryDelay);
    }
    return Promise.reject(new Error(400));
  }



static delay(milisec = 10000) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("resolved");
      }, milisec);
    });
```

}